# Как узнать количество запусков жесткого диска?

Tags: c#, hdd, ssd

пишу для себя на C#. Не могу найти информацию про того, как узнать количество запусков жесткого диска?

К примеру это есть в SSDLife или HDDLife.

Comment: [C# WMI HDD SMART Information](http://www.know24.net/blog/C+WMI+HDD+SMART+Information.aspx) ?

Comment: @tym32167 я думаю это то что я искал, чуть позже проверю, если что сообщу вам и можете в ответы добавить :) 

P.S
Который раз уже выручаете меня)